# An error between PowerPoint 2016 and PowerPoint 360 VBA macro

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have some code that runs flawlessly in PowerPoint 2016 but a user is reporting an error when they try and run it on PowerPoint 365. I don't have a copy of 365 and I can't seem to find any documentation that would support the error he is getting.

Objective of script:

- Two forms take in an agent's contact information and details
- The user also uploads a photo of the agent and their own photo
- The code then does a mass find and replace to update all the information.

The line of code causing the Object Error is:

```
if oPPtShp.HasTextFrame Then
```

Here is the full code. Again it runs without fail on PowerPoint 2016. Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub ImportPicture()

Dim oPPt As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPtSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim oPPtShp As PowerPoint.Shape

Set oPPt = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set oPPtSlide = oPPt.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

'Variables used to replace text information
Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
Dim oTmpRng As TextRange
'Combine the Brokerage City, Province and Postal in one string for easier replace
BrokerageCityProvPost = BrokerageInfoForm.BrokerageCity & ", " & BrokerageInfoForm.BrokerageProv & ", " & BrokerageInfoForm.BrokeragePostal.Value
'If the province is ON then set the Broker Designation to Brokerage, if not just leave it blank
Dim BrokerageDesignation As String
BrokerageDesignation = ""
If BrokerageInfoForm.BrokerageProv = "ON" Then BrokerageDesignation = "Brokerage"

    For Each oPPtSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oPPtShp In oPPtSlide.Shapes
            If oPPtShp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
                If oPPtShp.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderPicture Then
                    If oPPtShp.Name = "BrokerageImage1" Then
                        With oPPtShp
                            oPPtSlide.Shapes.AddPicture PhotosForm.BrokeragePhotoPath.Value, msoFalse, msoTrue, .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height
                        End With
                    Else
                        With oPPtShp
                            oPPtSlide.Shapes.AddPicture PhotosForm.AgentPhotoPath.Value, msoFalse, msoTrue, .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height
                     End With
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If oPPtShp.HasTextFrame Then
                If oPPtShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    With oPPtShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                        'Replace the relevant Agent Text
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Agent1 Name", AgentInfoForm.AgentFullName)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Agent1 Title", AgentInfoForm.AgentTitle)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Mobile1 Number", AgentInfoForm.AgentMobile)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Phone1 Number", AgentInfoForm.AgentPhone)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Agent1 Website", AgentInfoForm.AgentWebsite)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Agent1 Email", AgentInfoForm.AgentEmail)
                        'Replace the relevant fields for Agent 2
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Agent2 Name", AgentInfoForm.Agent2FullName)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Agent2 Title", AgentInfoForm.Agent2Title)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Mobile2 Number", AgentInfoForm.Agent2Mobile)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Phone2 Number", AgentInfoForm.Agent2Phone)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Agent2 Website", AgentInfoForm.Agent2Website)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Agent2 Email", AgentInfoForm.Agent2Email)
                        'Replace the relevant fields for Team Name
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Team Name", AgentInfoForm.TeamName)
                        'Replace the Brokerage Text
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Broker Name", BrokerageInfoForm.BrokerName)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Brokerage Name", BrokerageInfoForm.BrokerageName)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Brokerage Designation", BrokerageDesignation)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Brokerage Address", BrokerageInfoForm.BrokerageStreet1)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Broker Name", BrokerageInfoForm.BrokerName)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "City, Province, Postal Code", BrokerageCityProvPost)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Brokerage Website", BrokerageInfoForm.BrokerageWebsite)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Broker Email", BrokerageInfoForm.BrokerEmail)
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "Broker Phone", BrokerageInfoForm.BrokerPhone)
                        '.Text = Replace(.Text, "Broker Number", BrokerageInfoForm.BrokerPhone)
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next oPPtShp
    Next oPPtSlide

'Clean up the memory to clear everything
    Set fd = Nothing
    Set oPPtSlide = Nothing
    Set oPPt = Nothing



End Sub
```

And yes, I know this code is messy, I admit it is awful and I never really wanted to share it but here we are!

Comment: Please post the exact text of the error message.

Comment: I've run cut down copy of your code in Powerpoint 365. Works fine on the HasTextFrame line. I can't see any comment in the doco which would indicate a reason for your issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.hastextframe

Comment: I don't see any problems, but you could add a test for oPPtShp.Type to make sure you're only testing shape types that can have a text frame.